# How to express a number as a sum of $k$ squares?

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares

My question is the following: Show that for each integer $k \ge 5$, there is an integer $N(k)$ such that every integer $n \ge N(k)$ can be written as a sum of $k$ nonzero squares.

What is the process to prove this? I'm able to do this for the first few values of $k$, but I'm not able to find a version of induction that works for this.

Answer (score 1):

You state that you've already proved this for "the first few values of $k$", so only the inductive step remains.

1 is a perfect square. Hence, if you can write $n$ as a sum of $k$ nonzero squares, then you can write $n+1$ as a sum of $k+1$ nonzero squares, by letting one of those squares equal 1 and thus reducing to a previously solved problem.

It then follows that $N(k+1) \le N(k)+1$.

Comment: You have to prove the base case $k=5$ to make this induction work.

Comment: @TonyK Indeed you do, but OP says "I'm able to do this for the first few values of k" so presumably that's taken care of. I will edit my post to clarify this.

Comment: Unlikely the OP has a proof for 5 nonzero squares. See my brief answer

Answer (score 0):

In the last few pages of The Sensual Quadratic Form by J. H. Conway, it is proved that the numbers that are not the sum of four nonzero integer squares are 
$$ 1,3,5,9,11,17,29,41, \; 2 \cdot 4^m \; , \; 6 \cdot 4^m   \; , \; 14 \cdot 4^m   $$

ADDED: with four nonzero squares we get all odd numbers 43 or larger. Add a single 1 and we get all even numbers 44 or larger. Alternatively, add a single 4, get all odd numbers 47 or above with five nonzero squares. Together, we can write all numbers 47 or larger with five nonzero squares.